# How to access list of functions from event

Tags: javascript

```
class SwipeController {
  constructor(threshold) {
    var myElement = document.getElementById('swipecontainer');


    myElement.width = $( window ).width();
    myElement.height = $( window ).height();

    var mc = new Hammer(myElement);
    mc.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL, threshold: threshold });

    this.swiperight = new Array();
    this.swipeleft = new Array();
    mc.on("panright", function(ev) {
      alert(this.swiperight)
    this.swiperight.forEach(function(func) {

      func();
    })
    });

     mc.on("panleft", function(ev) {
      this.swipeleft.forEach(function(func) {
        func();
      })
    });

  }

  set swipeRight(value) {
      this.swiperight.push(value)
  }

  set swipeLeft(value) {
      this.swipeleft.push(value)
  } 
}

module.exports = SwipeController;
```

I realize that alert(this.swiperight) is showing as undefined because "this" is no longer the SwipeController class.  How do I go about doing this?  I'm trying to make this event trigger to trigger ANY event i connect to it, so I can handle all my swipe detection from one class.

Comment: Use an arrow function, bind the this context to the function or create a variable referencing this in the class itself, in order of personal preference ;)

Comment: Thanks for the life saver, I guess I couldn't word the question right and find the duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the `this` context of the callback is no longer the object of the class, but the object triggering the event.
To overcome this issue you can define a variable just before the callback definition that points to `this` and use it inside the callback (thus not incurring in this 'name conflict'):

```
var _this = this;
mc.on("panright", function(ev) {
    alert(_this.swiperight);
    _this.swiperight.forEach(function(func) {
        func();
    });
});

mc.on("panleft", function(ev) {
    _this.swipeleft.forEach(function(func) {
        func();
    });
});
```

Comment: well, the arrow function is so much easier ;) Seeing he uses constructors and classes already, I don't think that would be a problem for the OP. Btw, that's one of the top duplicate questions in javascript ;)